# Virt Block device resizing

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machines, libvirt, disk-image, diskmanagement

I am attempting to expand the size of a virtual disk on an existing image. I was successful to expand the virtual hard disk and partition thanks to [this guide](https://fatmin.com/2016/12/20/how-to-resize-a-qcow2-image-and-filesystem-with-virt-resize/), but noticed my virtual disk was still essentially full.

Taking a second look, the "20GB block device" (Second image) was not resized and is stuck at that 20GB (I resized the disk from ~20G to ~50G (added 30G)). In virt-manager, there is only the one virtual disk that is present; the qcow2 file I operated on to expand the disk. I assume that even though I expanded the partition that was 20G (matching the block device in size), that something is keeping this block device from accessing that expanded space.

When I try resizing the block device, I get the following:

```
$ sudo virt-resize --expand /dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv CS6250\ \(another\ copy\).qcow2 CS6250.qcow2
[   0.0] Examining CS6250 (another copy).qcow2
virt-resize: error: You cannot use --expand when there is no surplus space 
to expand into.  You need to make the target disk larger by at least 32.0K.

If reporting bugs, run virt-resize with debugging enabled and include the 
complete output:

  virt-resize -v -x [...]
```

Could someone enlighten me on what the 20GB block storage is, and how to get it resized accordingly?

A look at the main hard disk:

[image: Main hard disk]

A look at the 20GB Block Device:

[image: 20GB block device]

Comment: You installed your system with LVM. Are you not familiar with LVM?

Comment: Not as much as I should be. Also, this VM was provided for me in a class (non-sysadmin related)

Comment: That was it! Just didn't know how to frame the question well, thanks!